# How to update field value in jq when your are parsing the field's value to update the field (aka reformatting the value)

Tags: jq

Given a starting object like this:

```
[{
  "fieldA": "123",
  "fillDate": "20210101",
  "fieldB": "foo"
},
{
  "fieldA": "456",
  "fillDate": "20210102",
  "fieldB": "bar"
}]
```

I am reformatting the "fillDate" field from a string date, to something with the following structure:

```
fillDate": { "$date" : "2021-01-02T00:00:00Z"},
```

This is so it can be correctly imported into a MongoDB database. The following code works correctly for an array; but it eliminates out all of the other fields in the json document.

```
jq --raw-output '.[ ] | .fillDate | "\"fillDate\": { \"$date\" : \""+ .[0:4] + "-"+ .[4:6]+ "-"+ .[6:9] + "T00:00:00Z\"" + "},"'
```

So the output currently looks like this:

```
"fillDate": { "$date" : "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
"fillDate": { "$date" : "2021-01-02T00:00:00Z"},
```

When I need it to look like this:

```
{
  "fieldA": "123",
  "fillDate": { "$date" : "2021-01-01T00:00:00Z"},
  "fieldB": "foo"
},
{
  "fieldA": "456",
  "fillDate": { "$date" : "2021-01-02T00:00:00Z"},
  "fieldB": "bar"
}
```

I tried other suggestions on how to update the fillDate field directly, in a manner that would leave the other fields in-tact (while also iterating over the array); but could not get jq to accept anything without giving an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.[] | .fillDate = { "$date":   .fillDate |( .[0:4] + "-" + .[5:7] + .[6:9] + "T00:00:00Z")

snippet on jqplay
https://jqplay.org/s/JmYVXRzTnh